# Cookie was not setted

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, asp.net, xss

I work with asp.net xss scripting. One page send a post, than got a cookie.
In the header I read the cookie returns but the browser does not set it. 
so document.cookie is null

The header:

```
Set-Cookie:token=12ccc584-9f14-4c07-bbd9-0deba07b2a8e; expires=Fri, 30-Aug-2013 16:33:53 GMT; path=/
```

I allowed these headers at the backend:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 

HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", localost");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");



$.ajax(
            {
                url: "http://localhost:49670/api/authentication",
                type:"post",
                data: loginDTO,
                success: function() {
                    console.log("works");
            console.log("cookies: ", document.cookie);
            },
            error: function(request, status, error){
                console.error(request.responseText);
                },
                xhrFields: {
                  withCredentials: true
               }
            });
```

Why was not the cookie setted?

Answer (score 0):

Because you wrote "localost" and not localhost?